# Remove edges in mirror

Tags: edges, mirror, topology, retopology

I want to modify the topology of a model, but when I was eliminating edge loops with symmetry, I realized that the edges of the opposite side were not erased along with the ones I had selected.
[image]

Is there a way to erase the geometry in both parts without resorting to cutting the mesh in half and using the mirror modifier?
I use blender 2.91 and testing 2.92.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not use the mirror modifier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press <kbd>A</kbd> to select whole mesh, then <kbd>F3</kbd> and search for **Symmetrize**; make sure to choose the correct direction.

[image]